# Android firebase query, get one result only. Different result when button is pressed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 Counter4 = Counter2 - Counter1 + 1;
    Query qname = mDatabase.child("variablex").equalTo(variablexofuser).getRef().getParent().limitToFirst(Counter1).limitToLast(Counter4);
```

This is the code i am trying to use. Everytime a button is pressed, Counter1 gets increased by 1. The Counter2 is the number of users in the database with the variablex equal to the variablex of the logged user.

```
 Query qname3 = mDatabase.child("variablex").equalTo(variablexofuser).getRef();
    qname3.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            testref = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            Counter2 = (int) testref;
        }
```

The intention is to get the first user that meets the criteria (variablex = variablexofuser), then the second user that meets the criteria when the button is pressed a second time, and so on. So basically get only one different result every time the button is pressed. Will my code work and if not can you tell why? Is there maybe a more simple, or correct way of achieving this? 
Thank you!

```
{
  "Mp6FLLdcSeXpfGPwP5i0ZBNZxd63" : {
    "Age" : "20",
    "Full name" : "Mike",
    "Intent" : "Both",
    "Reward" : "Nothing ",
    "Variablex" : "one name",
    "imageuri" : "images/Mp6FLLdcSeXpfGPwP5i0ZBNZxd63.jpeg"
  },
  "fWJcCPF16dUMKn1Sxz01VjF9Kgq2" : {
    "Age" : "19",
    "Full name" : "Other guy",
    "Intent" : "Looking for help",
    "Reward" : "nothing ",
    "Variablex" : "one name",
    "imageuri" : "images/fWJcCPF16dUMKn1Sxz01VjF9Kgq2"
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like an unlikely fragment of code `mDatabase.child("variablex").equalTo(variablexofuser)`. Can you edit your question (there's a link under it) to include a snippet of the JSON you are reading (as text, no screenshot)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: {
  "Mp6FLLdcSeXpfGPwP5i0ZBNZxd63" : {
    "Age" : "20",
    "Full name" : "Mike",
    "Intent" : "Both",
    "Reward" : "Nothing ",
    "Variablex" : "one name",
    "imageuri" : "images/Mp6FLLdcSeXpfGPwP5i0ZBNZxd63.jpeg"
  },
  "fWJcCPF16dUMKn1Sxz01VjF9Kgq2" : {
    "Age" : "19",
    "Full name" : "Other guy",
    "Intent" : "Looking for help",
    "Reward" : "nothing ",
    "Variablex" : "one name",
    "imageuri" : "images/fWJcCPF16dUMKn1Sxz01VjF9Kgq2"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query the child nodes of a location with the Firebase Database, you first call `orderByChild()` with the property that you want to order/filter on.

You also should **not** call `getRef()` at the end of the query, because that will then just give you an *unfiltered* list of the messages again.

So:

```
Query qname3 = mDatabase.orderByChild("variablex").equalTo(variablexofuser);
qname3.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        testref = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        Counter2 = (int) testref;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but when i click the button to perform the first query (the first lines of code) Query qname, crashes the activity. The goal of this whole thing is to limit my results to the first user with the same variablex as the logged user, when the button is clicked once, then to limit the results to only the second user that meets the criteria when the button is clicked for a second time, and so on until there are no more users to display or it shows the first one again. Is there a way you can help me with this? I think the combination of limittofirst and limittolast is the issue.

Comment: I have no idea what `Counter2` etc are. But if you are trying to do offset-based queries, that's not how Firebase works. Firebase Database queries are cursor-based, not offset based. So: you can only get the next few items, if you know the `variablex` value (and possibly the key) of the item at which to start. You pass those into `ref.orderByChild("variablex").startAt("variablexvaluetostartat", "keyofitemtostartat").limitToFirst(1)`.